# Odoo delete number of records on group by tree

Tags: python, xml, group-by, odoo

Anybody knows how or where to hide the total number of records/lines displayed when applying a group by on a tree view.

Displayed between the brackets in the image below.

[image]

Comment: First guess: look into `read_group()`

Comment: You need to check in web framework, how odoo design group by.